# REST collection API: return a list of URL or a list of objects

Tags: json, rest

I'm designing a REST API and apparently there are collections. I've seen two different kind of designs:

One is to return a list of `href` to individual resources:

```
{
  'list':
     [
    'http://xxxx',
    'http://xxxx',
    'http://xxxx'
     ]
}
```

The other way is to include all the individual objects in the response:

```
[
  {
     foo: bar
  }
  {
     bar: foo
  }
]
```

What are the pros and cons of each approach?

Comment: What do you want your service to return and how do you want to use it ?

Comment: @Cubi that's kind of my question: under what situation should one use which?

Answer (score 0):

I would say a list of URLs is rarely useful. Often I see the pattern used more like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {…},
    {…}
  ]
}
```

This allows you as a developer to give context about the entire collection. The [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org) and [JSON-LD](http://json-ld.org) specs take advantage of this to the fullest. If you are trying to fully comply with HATEOS it also allows to embed links and pagination information straight into the response.

The second response is more of idiomatic JavaScript/JSON. It loses the ability to have in-object context information, however that info can just as well go in the response headers. It can also be easier for your API Clients to digest and it is easily interoperable with other APIs.

Another definitely interesting approach is [Line Delimited JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_Delimited_JSON) which looks more like this:

```
{ "foo": "bar" }
{ "bar": "foo" }
{ "bax": "bux" }
{ "buz": "bax" }
```